# How to test CSS file load time?

Tags: html, css, load-time

I want to make CSS file load into HTML file time tester, so I search for idea how to test CSS file load time:

1) When I use import() function;
2) When I use link tag

Should I use PHP timers or something?

Comment: inspect element in chrome.... done.

Comment: Do you want to do something with it in code, or just see and compare visually?

Comment: I need compare visually with graphics.

Answer (score 0):

In most browsers you can open a "Developer Mode" or something like that. There you can go to the "Network"-Tab and reload the page. Then you can see how long each page needs to load.

Cheers

PS: If you have questions to a specific browser, just post it in the comments.

Comment: I tried to test in Network mode CSS include types: import vs link. So, the result shows that import method is few ms faster than link. So, why all headings sounds like "avoid import"?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest I've never used it before. Maybe it is (like most PHP functions) quite difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chrome devtools network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) gives you a display of load times for each resource. You'll be able to see how fast your CSS file is loading. If you're not using chrome, modern browsers have inspector tools built in.